# Is it possible to create a non-empty file without write_close and rename event?

Tags: files, sftp, hard-link, inotify

The reason why I am asking is because I'm using [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) (not to confuse with a gadget device) to watch for filesystem events (in my case - file creation/renaming).

What I cannot explain is this log:

```
/path/to/file.ext.filepart 0 IN_MODIFY 
/path/to/file.ext.filepart 0 IN_MODIFY 
/path/to/file.ext.filepart 0 IN_MODIFY 
/path/to/file.ext.filepart 0 IN_MODIFY 
/path/to/file.ext.filepart 0 IN_CLOSE_WRITE 
/path/to/file.ext 0 IN_CREATE 
/path/to/file.ext.filepart 0 IN_DELETE 
/path/to/file.ext 0 IN_ATTRIB
```

To get it I've copied a `file.ext` from a remote machine using WinSCP with temporary file creation option turned on (so that it was either no file `file.ext` at all, in case if transfer was terminated, or the complete file was in the destination).

And what confuses me is that the `/path/to/file.ext` is only created `IN_CREATE` and its attributes modified `IN_ATTRIB` (not sure which ones though, but I think that's where all the magic happens).

The strangest thing here is that:

1. The `file.ext` is not a result of moving `file.ext.filepart` - there would be a different move event
2. The `file.ext` is not a result of copying `file.ext.filepart` - there would be a bunch of write events following by `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`

So my question is - what is happening here under the hood: how the `file.ext` was created with the contents without an explicit rename or data copy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ inotifywait -m /tmp
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
/tmp/ CREATE file.ext.filepart
/tmp/ OPEN file.ext.filepart
/tmp/ MODIFY file.ext.filepart
/tmp/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE file.ext.filepart
/tmp/ CREATE file.ext
/tmp/ DELETE file.ext.filepart
```

Transcript from running

```
$ echo hello >/tmp/file.ext.filepart
$ ln /tmp/file.ext.filepart /tmp/file.ext         
$ rm /tmp/file.ext.filepart
```

Moving a file generates a `move` event, but creating a hard link generates the same `create` event as creating a new, empty file (as do `mkfifo` and other ways to create files).

Why does the SCP or SFTP server creates a hard link then remove the temporary file rather than moving the temporary file into place? In the source code of OpenSSH (portable 6.0), in `sftp-server.c`, in the function `process_rename`, I see the following code (reformatted and simplified to illustrate the part I want to show):

```
if (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)) {
    /* Race-free rename of regular files */
    if (link(oldpath, newpath) == -1) {
         if (errno == EOPNOTSUPP || errno == ENOSYS) {
            /* fs doesn't support links, so fall back to stat+rename.  This is racy. */
            if (stat(newpath, &st) == -1) {
                rename(oldpath, newpath) == -1)
            }
        }
    } else {
        unlink(newpath);
    }
}
```

That is: try to create a hard link from the temporary file name to the desired file name, then remove the temporary file. If creating the hard link doesn't work because the OS or the filesystem doesn't support that, fall back to a different method: test if the desired file exists, and if doesn't, rename the temporary file. So the point is to rename the temporary file to its final location without risking overwriting a file that may have been created while the copy was in progress. Renaming wouldn't do because `rename` overwrites the target file if it exists.

Comment: Yep, I also suspected it's a hardlink, thanks.